# Unable to parse JSON using jq tool due to node name containing unexpected character

Tags: json, bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci, jq

I tried with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse some JSON output inside my [GitLab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/) pipeline so I can extract needed information. I've tried many different ways, but I can't get the desired information out of the target node, because it has special characters and when I get to that node, the pipeline fails in each case. This is the current state of my pipeline.

This is the problematic job:

```
get results (dev branch):
  stage: Results of scanning image
  variables:
    RESULTS: ""
    STATUS: ""
    SEVERITY: ""
  image: alpine
  only:
    refs:
      - dev
  allow_failure: true
  before_script:
    - apk update && apk upgrade
    - apk --no-cache add curl
    - apk add jq
  script:
    - 'RESULTS=$(curl -H "Authorization: Basic `echo -n ${HARBOR_USER}:${HARBOR_PASSWORD} | base64`" -X GET "https://url.to.registry/api/v2.0/projects/project/repositories/repo-name/artifacts/latest?page=1&page_size=10&with_tag=true&with_label=true&with_scan_overview=true&with_signature=true&with_immutable_status=true")'
    - echo $RESULTS
    - RESULTS=$RESULTS | tr 'application/vnd.scanner.adapter.vuln.report.harbor+json; ' 'myobject'
    - echo $RESULTS
    - "STATUS=$RESULTS | jq '.scan_overview .myobjectversion=1.0 .scan_status'"
    - "SEVERITY=$RESULTS | jq '.scan_overview .myobjectversion=1.0 .severity'"
    - echo "Printing the results of the image scanning process on Harbor registry:"
    - echo "status of scan:$STATUS"
    - echo "severity of scan:$SEVERITY"
    - echo "For more information of scan results please visit Harbor registry!"
  tags:
    - dev
    - docker
```

This is the JSON output that I get from the curl command:

```
{
   "addition_links":{
      "build_history":{
         "absolute":false,
         "href":"..."
      },
      "vulnerabilities":{
         "absolute":false,
         "href":"...."
      }
   },
   "digest":"sha256:bcd665be2b7c6725b410029db385d7c6c71a9ce557427cbd0f54d01a9",
   "extra_attrs":{
      "architecture":"amd64",
      "author":null,
      "created":"2021-10-22T10:28:46.058276455Z",
      "os":"linux"
   },
   "icon":"sha256:0048162a053ee7518615bef084403614f8bca43b40ae2e762e11e06",
   "id":362,
   "labels":null,
   "manifest_media_type":"application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
   "media_type":"application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
   "project_id":3,
   "pull_time":"2021-10-22T10:28:55.305Z",
   "push_time":"2021-10-22T10:28:49.341Z",
   "references":null,
   "repository_id":12,
   "scan_overview":{
      "application/vnd.scanner.adapter.vuln.report.harbor+json; version=1.0":{
         "complete_percent":100,
         "duration":8,
         "end_time":"2021-10-22T10:28:57.356Z",
         "report_id":"e83854eb-2304-4c58-85c9-a3e0fd9067a8",
         "scan_status":"Success",
         "severity":"Critical",
         "start_time":"2021-10-22T10:28:49.827Z",
         "summary":{
            "summary":{
               "Critical":7,
               "High":47,
               "Low":18,
               "Medium":47
            },
            "total":119
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My initial idea was to using `jq` to extract `scan_status` and `severity` with this command:

```
RESULTS=$RESULTS | jq '.scan_overview .application/vnd.scanner.adapter.vuln.report.harbor+json; version=1.0 .scan_status'
```

after running that command I got this error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.scan_overview .application/vnd.scanner.adapter.vuln.report.harbor+json; version=1.0 .scan_status                                                                       
jq: 1 compile error
```

Now I am trying text replacement, but that doesn't work either.

How should I proceed in this case?

Answer (score 4):

Use square brackets and double quotes around the problematic key:

```
jq '.scan_overview["application/vnd.scanner.adapter.vuln.report.harbor+json; version=1.0"].scan_status'
```

Also, this doesn't do what you think:

```
RESULTS=$RESULTS | tr 'application/vnd.scanner.adapter.vuln.report.harbor+json; ' 'myobject'
```

First of all, `tr` doesn't replace strings, it replaces characters. `sed` can replace strings.

Moreover, the pipe `|` is used when the left hand side produces output. Variable assignment doesn't produce any output.

Finally, to assign the output of a command to a variable, you need to use Command Substitution:

```
var=$(command)
    ~~       ~
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I managed to fix the error I had, everything works great now!

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the key in question inside barckets and quotes like so:

```
.scan_overview["application/vnd.scanner.adapter.vuln.report.harbor+json; version=1.0"].scan_status
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/UgRiZB0jGh)

Answer (score 2):

From a shell syntax perspective, this looks wrong:

```sh
RESULTS=$RESULTS | jq '...'
```

Assigning a variable produces no output, so `jq` on the other side of the pipe has no input.

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)*

Comment: Why are you using Stack Overflow as a forum after 13 years and 213,896 reputation points? [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115).

Answer (score 1):

If it is okay for you to ignore the name of the problematic key, then you can substitute it with empty brackets:

```
RESULTS=$RESULTS | jq '.scan_overview [] .scan_status'
```

This is a bit sloppy and may match more than you would like, but in your narrow example, it will successfully pull out the value of `.scan_status`.

The reason this works, in this case, is because the `application/vnd...` property is the *only* property in the `scan_overview` object.

A more confident match would be achievable by using more quotes:

```
RESULTS=$RESULTS | jq '.scan_overview ."application/vnd.scanner.adapter.vuln.report.harbor+json; version=1.0" .scan_status'
```